# add clicked value to stored value query

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is for a quiz. The user has a question with a choice of three answers.  The answers are buttons. Each button has a value.  When the user clicks the button, it gives a value then moves onto the next question.  And this process repeats through a series of 7 questions.  During this process, I want it to add each of the values clicked and have an accumulated total at the end.

I'm not sure if I should create a loop for this?  I also want to note that this is being done without refreshing the page using .show and .hide features to the different sections of the quiz.

Thanks for your help!

Here are the buttons:

```html
<button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER  1</button>
     <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER  2</button>
     <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER  3</button>
```

```js
 function charValue () {
  $(this).val();
 }
 
 var storedValue = $(this).$("button").data(charValue);
 var accumValue = storedValue + charValue;
 
 $("button").on('click', charValue);
```

Comment: if you want to do it scalable with clean code get into some MVVM like knockout.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a final button at the end, for example:

```
<button id="finalbutton">Get Results</button>
```

And then create the javascript like so:

```
var accumValue = 0;

$("button").on('click', function() {

    if(!$(this).attr('value')) {
        return;
    }

    accumValue += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
});

$('#finalbutton').on('click', function() {
    alert(accumValue);
});
```

Comment: You should parse with `parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10);` to ensure the correct number base. [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: The pitfall with this solution is if you allow the user to change their answer (or "go back" so to speak) it will keep adding to the total beyond the max score. I would personally store each answer is an object or array, and sum the values when I needed the total

Comment: This solution works great!  Thank you! 

For this, they will not be able to go back and change their answer, so no worries there.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var curScore = parseInt($("span").text(), 10);
  var newScore = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  $("span").text(curScore + newScore);
  $(this).parent().hide();
  $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

```css
.Question{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Question" style="display: block;">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>

  <button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER 1</button>
  <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
  <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER 3</button>
</div>
<div class="Question">
  <h3>Question 2</h3>

  <button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER 1</button>
  <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
  <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER 3</button>
</div>
<div class="Question">
  <h3>Question 3</h3>

  <button class="blue" id="goat" value="5">ANSWER 1</button>
  <button class="blue" id="bird" value="10">ANSWER 2</button>
  <button class="blue" id="fish" value="15">ANSWER 3</button>
</div>
<p>The final score is <span>0</span>
</p>
```

You can use `.val()` to get value and sum them.

To hide the current question after choose an answer, and show next one, use code:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
$(this).parent().next().show();
```

Comment: This works great as well.  Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: I am wondering, I would like to style the button areas more and would like them in a list format (<ul><li>).  I've updated your code but I want them to display side by side instead of stacked when I use this <li> format.  I tried updating to display: inline-block; 
here: <div class="Question" style="display: block;"> but this does not work.  Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code and show sum at the end, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mz64rkyp/) here

```
var sum= 0;
$("button").click(function() {
        sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
        //alert(sum);
});
```

Comment: You should parse with `parseInt($(this).val(), 10);` to ensure the correct number base. [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score -3):

You can put all your questions on the same page.
As the user completes the questions, hide the completed questions and show the next unanswered question.

every time one answers a question, add the selected answer to your submission form. When the user finished all the questions show the submit button, and let one submit his answers.

Comment: Why are you suggesting what the OP has already mentioned they are trying to do? OP already said they are displaying them in same page and using show/hide functions. The Problem is with adding up the values associated with the buttons

Comment: This does not answer the question and the OP says he is already doing that!